# foldr vs foldr1 usage in Haskell

Tags: haskell

If I write:

```
> let xs = [1,5,19,2,-3,5]
> foldr max 0 xs
19

> foldr1 max xs
19
```

And if I write (I know, the initial value is incorrect here for a generic maximum function...):

```
> let maximum' = foldr max 0
> maximum' xs
19
```

But if I write:

```
> let maximum2' = foldr1 max
> maximum2' xs
```

the response is:

```
<interactive>:61:11:
    Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `Integer'
    Expected type: [()]
      Actual type: [Integer]
    In the first argument of maximum2', namely `xs'
    In the expression: maximum2' xs
```

I am new to Haskell. What am I doing wrong? (Can't decipher the error message...) How to use `foldr1` with `max`? Thanks.

EDIT (AFTER ACCEPTING ANSWER):

Just to show some more examples of the defaulting rules' effect (the answer explains these, too):

Example 1:

```
> let max' = max
> :t max
max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a

> :t max' 
max' :: () -> () -> ()
```

Example 2:

```
> let plus = (+)
> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

> :t plus 
plus :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Comment: The dreaded monomorphism restriction.

Comment: funnily enough `:t foldr1 max` gives `Ord a => [a] -> a` and `let maximum' l = foldr1 max l` works as expected

Comment: @augustss missing link to [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is to do with the polymorphism of the types and GHCi's defaulting.  The type of `max` is polymorphic:

```
> :t max
max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

In the case of `maximum'`, the compiler can see that `a` is some sort of number, and GHCi defaults the number to Integer:

```
> :t maximum'
maximum' :: [Integer] -> Integer
```

In the case of `maximum2'` it has less clues, and defaults `a` to the unit type:

```
> :t maximum2'
maximum2' :: [()] -> ()
```

If you provide a type signature, all is well:

```
> let maximum3' :: Ord a => [a] -> a ; maximum3' = foldr1 max
> :t maximum3'
maximum3' :: Ord a => [a] -> a
```

I think GHCi's defaulting rules are there to make certain other cases where the types are omitted easier -- see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#id484837

Comment: Wow! Very helpful answer, thanks! And the link is very useful, too!