# What make the difference between `:t` and let expression in GHCi

Tags: haskell

I want to make a toy function that produces a `Maybe a` and then lift `show` to make it a `Maybe String`, but the outcome was weird for me:

```
λ> :t liftM show . Just
liftM show . Just :: Show a1 => a1 -> Maybe String
λ> liftM show . Just $ 10
Just "10"
λ> let f = liftM show . Just
λ> f 10

<interactive>:9:3:
    No instance for (Num ()) arising from the literal `10'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ())
    In the first argument of `f', namely `10'
    In the expression: f 10
    In an equation for `it': it = f 10
λ> :t f
f :: () -> Maybe String
λ> let g = liftM show . Just :: (Show a) => a -> Maybe String
λ> :t g
g :: () -> Maybe String
λ> let h = liftM show . Just :: Int -> Maybe String
λ> :t h
h :: Int -> Maybe String
```

I guess it has something to do with type inference, but I really don't know what happened:

- where did that mysterious `()` come from?
- why GHCi didn't complain about ambiguousness?

Comment: possible duplicate of [foldr vs foldr1 usage in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661866/foldr-vs-foldr1-usage-in-haskell)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dum-duuum!

Next victim of the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

What happens is this: for a definition that looks like a "constant variable" (in the sense that other languages might also use, i.e. not of function type), like `f = ...`, it is assumed that you wish it to actually behave like a constant ([CAF](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/CAF), to be precise). That means, it must not be polymorphic, since with parametric polymorphism there's basically an extra implicit argument to the function (the information which type `a1` should be).

To achieve this actual-const-ness, ghci [*defaults*](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#2.4.7) this type variable to whatever specific type it deems least inappropriate. Here, the only constraint is `Show`; the simplest type fulfilling that is `()`.

The "correct" way of getting around this is to turn off the monomorphism restriction:

> Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction 
>   Prelude> :m +Control.Monad
>   Prelude Control.Monad> let f = liftM show . Just
>   Prelude Control.Monad> f 10
>   Just "10"

Alternatively, you can, like in an actual source file you always should, give proper signatures to identifiers in ghci:

> Prelude Control.Monad> let g :: Show a => a -> Maybe String; g = liftM show . Just
>   Prelude Control.Monad> g 10
>   Just "10"

Doing that only on the RHS of the `=` doesn't work, since the monomorphism restriction kicks in only after that is resolved and defaults away the variables (unless, as in `h`, there are no variables in the first place because you gave a monomorphic signature to the RHS).

Still another thing you can do, simply give the function an explicit argument, then the monomorphism restriction doesn't apply at all. I.e., write it non–point-free:

> Prelude Control.Monad> let i a = liftM show $ Just a
>   Prelude Control.Monad> i 10
>   Just "10"

Comment: would it do any damage if I put `NoMonomorphismRestriction` in my `.ghci`?

Comment: Not really. Worst that's realistic is, some things will be slower because there's no sharing of polymorphic constants anymore, but unlikely to be an issue.